# How could I split a list based on first character of word and put them in a dictionary without using modules?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to split the following list according to the starting character of each word:

```
word_list = ['be','have','do','say','get','make','go','know','take','see','come','think',
     'look','want','give','use','find','tell','ask','work','seem','feel','leave','call']
```

and put them in a dictionary without using modules.

This is what I tried:

```
word_list = ['be','have','do','say','get','make','go','know','take','see','come','think',
     'look','want','give','use','find','tell','ask','work','seem','feel','leave','call']
n = 'a'
x = []

dictionary = dict()

for c in range(97, 123):
        x.append(chr(c))
print(x)
print()

for i in x:
    for j in word_list:
        if i in dictionary.keys():
            if j.startswith(i):
                dictionary[i].append(j)
            else:
                dictionary = [j]
print(dictionary)
```

The expected results:

```
dictionary = {'a':['ask'],'b':['be'],...................}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below,

```
word_list = ['be','have','do','say','get','make','go','know','take','see','come','think',
     'look','want','give','use','find','tell','ask','work','seem','feel','leave','call']

dictionary = dict()
for c in map(chr,range(97, 123)):
    words = [i for i in word_list if i.startswith(c)]
    if words:
        dictionary[c] = words
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: This has to iterate over `word_list` 26 times, which is probably less efficient than other methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setdefault` or `defaultdict`:

```
word_list = ['be','have','do','say','get','make','go','know','take','see','come','think',
     'look','want','give','use','find','tell','ask','work','seem','feel','leave','call']

result = {}
for word in word_list:
    result.setdefault(word[0], []).append(word)

# OR

from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for word in word_list:
    result[word[0]].append(word)
```

`defaultdict` has the exact same interface as `dict` otherwise, so it can be used anywhere you need a `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that there are no keys in your dictionary to start with, so `if i in dictionary.keys():` is never true because you never execute any code to put a key into the dictionary. Basically you need to add to the dictionary when `j` starts with `i` and `i` is not already a key in the dictionary:

```
for i in x:
    for j in word_list:
        if i in dictionary.keys():
            if j.startswith(i):
                dictionary[i].append(j)
        elif j.startswith(i):
            dictionary[i] = [j]
print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'f': ['find', 'feel'], 
 'l': ['look', 'leave'],
 'd': ['do'],
 'g': ['get', 'go', 'give'],
 't': ['take', 'think', 'tell'],
 'h': ['have'],
 'u': ['use'],
 's': ['say', 'see', 'seem'],
 'm': ['make'],
 'b': ['be'],
 'a': ['ask'],
 'w': ['want', 'work'],
 'k': ['know'],
 'c': ['come', 'call']
}
```

You can achieve the same result with a nested dictionary/list comprehension:

```
dictionary = { c : [w for w in word_list if w.startswith(c)] for c in [w[:1] for w in word_list] }
```

Comment: @SH_IQ no worries. I've also added a single line solution if you're interested.

Comment: Yes, dear. I have seen your answer. it is really good. Thank you so much.